Even if vs even though

______ she can't drive, she has a car.

A. Even   B. Even when    C. Even if     D. Even though
Apparently the  answer is D but I find C also makes sense：

Even if she can't drive, she still has a car.

What do you think?

C only really makes sense if the speaker doesn't know whether she can drive. Sometimes the "not known" condition may be something that's inherently uncertain, or that people might have different opinions about. "Even if she's not the best-looking girl in her class, she won't be stuck with no-one inviting her to the prom" at least admits of the possibility that she might be the best looking (though she probably isn't, by a wide margin! :). But Even though in that context would be positively asserting that's she's definitely not the most attractive girl in her class.

Things get more subtle when the "condition" (can drive, is best-looking) is negated. But I think wherever you got that multi-choice question from is possibly not a trustworthy source.

I do; however, agree that the example cited by the OP is a very poor one, logically and semantically speaking.
I don't think you can purchase a car without a driving licence, ergo you cannot own a car. That people drive cars without having a driver's license is a fact but they don't usually own the vehicle. A much better and very common example is talking about the rain. Even though it rained / was raining, the match was not cancelled. Some will say that "even if" is also acceptable, in everyday life this may be true but not in an English language exam.

@Mari-LouA: Of course you can own a car even if you don't drive and have never passed a test. But it's a bad example because it's perfectly possible the speaker doesn't know whether she can drive.

@FumbleFingers  I don't think you can purchase a car from a car dealer and drive it off without a full driver's license. What about car insurance? I might be wrong because I've never bought a car in the UK but if it is legal to purchase a car despite not being qualified it must be a very rare occurrence. It's true that the speaker (C) is imagining  a hypothetical situation. But like I said, the test example is not a good one for more than one reason.

@Mari-LouA: Obviously you can't legally drive it off if you don't have a license. But in the UK you can certainly pay for it and be the registered owner, and have someone else drive it away. And I find it hard to believe all Italian car dealers (and all the people who sell their old car privately) could be required to check that whoever they sell to has a valid driver's license.

@FumbleFingers When you driving any car in Italy, you must have on your person your driver's license, that's the law in Italy. I know it's different in the UK. But it shows why it's not a burden, in Italy, to verify whether you are the owner of a valid driving licence. Can we at least agree that the situation is rare and impractical, or do you want to have the last word, as you are wont to do? If you can't resist,  you're proving  me that I am right about one thing! ;)

Expressions of the form “A, even though B” mean—without explicitly stating as much—that B holds (in other words that B is true), whereas “A, even if B” means that A holds regardless whether B does. So the latter can be used to mean “even in the case that B is false.”
Thus, Two is a prime number, even though it is even is fine, as is Grandma used to walk to school every day, even if it was snowing. But in neither sentence could we replace the one of though and if with the other.

Even if would work in
Even if she can't drive, she will still buy a car.
There’s a connection here between the two clauses.  The buying is a future decision and will be made despite her inability to drive.
In the original example, there is no connection between the two clauses, that is, the imagined scenario of her being unable to drive and her owning a car at present.  The use of even if leads us to expect some kind of decisions, but in this case the owning of the car is already a fact, and no further decisions will apply.
Edit
Even if could also work if the speaker is unaware of and doesn’t care about the subject’s ability to drive.
For the original post, we should still use Even though.

Can you help me judge the correctness of these two sentences：1.  IF she can't drive，she has a car. "IF" is stressed (cf. 2.   If she is not a genius, she is smart)

I disagree that C can't be used (see my comment under the Q). It's relatively unlikely, so can probably be ignored in the context of learners, but C is certainly possible if the speaker doesn't know (also perhaps, doesn't care) whether she can drive. But I suspect that OP's multiple-choice test question is yet another example of misleading simplistic garbage from a non-Anglophone source.

@FumbleFingers please stop answering questions in comments, you know it shouldn't be done for several reasons 1. you undermine the real answers that are posted. 2. If you partially or totally disagree with someone's answer you should post an answer yourself 3. It encourages users to post answers in comments too also because comments cannot be downvoted 4. Without downvotes we don't know for certain whether a comment is not only correct but also accurate and unbiased.

@Mari-LouA: The "correct" answer has already been provided by Paul. Also, I haven't checked yet, but I'd say this even if / even though distinction has almost certainly been asked and answered before.

@FumbleFingers In fact the question is currently closed as a duplicate but I don't see any upvote on Paul's answer though...

Thanks! @FumbleFingers.  Alright, C could work, and I think it means I don’t know whether she can drive (and I don’t care), she has a car. The main message is in the last clause.
